# Como usar PROCV para procurar códigos em duas planilhas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, procv

No Excel 365, versão 1907, e Windows 10, tenho uma arquivo XLSX com duas planilhas quase iguais - Planilha1 e Planilha2.

Conteúdo da Planilha1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conteúdo da Planilha2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu desejo verificar na Planilha2 se os números de "doc" existem na Planilha1

Então fiz assim em uma nova coluna na Planilha2:

```
=SEERRO(PROCV(B2;Planilha1!A$2:B$5;2;FALSO); "Não")
```

Mas todos os resultados aparecem como "Não", apesar de três códigos em "doc" existirem nas duas planilhas

Por favor, alguém sabe o que pode estar errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando as referências e a formulá errada, veja o resultado na imagem abaixo.

1) Considere estar com a planilha 2 ativa, a qual você deseja colocar a fórmula na célula C3;

2) Você inicie escrevendo na C3 "=SEERRO(PROCV(", selecione na planilha 2 a célula B3, pois você deseja iniciar sua pesquisa a partir dessa célula;

3) Vá na planilha 1 e selecione a coluna B inteira, pois é nesta que estão os dados pesquisados. Neste momento a formulá vai ficar assim: "=SEERRO(PROCV(B3;Planilha1!B:B;"...

4) Repare que você selecionou apenas a coluna B na planilha 1, portanto, seu índice inicia em 1 (você escreveu 2 em sua fórmula).

5) Então, em seguida, continue a escrita de sua fórmula que deverá ser assim:

```
=SEERRO(PROCV(B3;Planilha1!B:B;1;FALSO); "Não")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]